# Flutter setup: transfer android Sdk from device to another

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to setup Flutter on my friend's device and ,After I ran flutter doctor the **Android Sdk** was missing and i want to transfer the **Sdk** from my device to his without downloading it ,
**How can I do it**?.
**also** i tried moving the flutter **Sdk** and it worked so i hope that there is a way to do the same with android **Sdk**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked.

**What I did:** I copied the whole Android folder that contains the SDK and pasted it on my friend's device. I had to copy the the `JDK` folder to his device and set the `Java_home` path for it. Afterwards, when I ran the Flutter project, it started downloading the **Web SDK** (I did not know how to copy it) and it ran `Gradle Task AssembleDebug` to create The `.gradle` folder in the `C:\Users\Username` section. I did not try to copy that folder, but it may work.